approximating a shape with a line
I have an image that has been converted to an svg.
The conversion looks fine, but it has prefered to use fill instead of stroke.
This in itself is not a bad thing in terms of converting a raster image to an svg.
And the lines looks pretty detailed:

The issue is that I need a stroke path that approximates this line.
I know that I will be loosing data/detail by doing this, and that is perfectly fine, I just want an approximation using a fixed width stroke path.
Is there a known algorithm for this?

Don't know a canned image algorithm for this off hand, but the problem you describe strongly reminds me of Linear Regression. Though it would make your stroke into only one line rather than a path.

Are you looking for an algorithm which approximates the shape/ pixels by a line with given thickness, or one which also dtermines the thickness or other svg stroke line prpertierties?

@DocBrown If I understand your question correctly I want an algorithm that approximates the shape and thickness. So I do not care about other stroke line properties such as color. I am only interested in x/y coordinates and an approximate thickness of the entire line/stroke

Some open source packages implement algorithms for doing this, e.g., Inkscape.

I don't think there is "one algorithm" for this. I think one can break down the problem into separate steps and construct a solution by choosing or creating algorithms for the steps.

... the obvious first step would be to split the shape into connected components.
